# Filling names into a column with the fill() funciton

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a column I am trying to use the fill() function in tidyr to fill the blanks with the string that preceded it.

For example I would like to go from:

```
col_name
   NAME1
 (blank)
   NAME2
 (blank)
```

To:

```
col_name
   NAME1
   NAME1
   NAME2
   NAME2
```

When I type the code:

```
fill(df, col_name)
```

the console registers the syntax but the original output is still the same.

I would like a solution that I can keep in the pipes %>%

Answer (score 3):

You might need to set the 'blank' values to `NA` first. For example, if your `(blank)` values are empty strings `""`, convert them to `NA` first then `fill` should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col_name = c("NAME1", "", "NAME2", ""))
df %>% 
  mutate(col_name = na_if(col_name == "")) %>% 
  fill(col_name)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   col_name
#>      <chr>
#> 1    NAME1
#> 2    NAME1
#> 3    NAME2
#> 4    NAME2
```

Comment: The `mutate` can also be written as `mutate(col_name = na_if(col_name, ''))`.

Comment: @Paul, good point! Answer has been edited to include `na_if` instead of `if_else`.